# WCF service call from console app runs fine when manually executed but when it is running on the scheduled time it gives time out before one minute

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

WCF service call from console app runs fine when manually executed but when it is running on the scheduled time it gives time out before one minute. Also, although it is throwing an exception the process in WCF service call is completed without any error. What could be the issue?

Comment: please check error details in event viewer or task  scheduler history if it is scheduled using task scheduler

Comment: 2020-02-13 03:15:23.3940: service started
2020-02-13 03:16:19.9865:
Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)